# NullPointerException is Java while trying to Animate with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I get a nullPointerException when I am trying to create my player and animate him. I don't really understand whats wrong.
Here is the code:

```
package com.sheep.game.Sprites;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.sheep.game.Screens.PlayScreen;

public class Player extends Sprite {

    float elapsedTime = 0;

    public Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
    public Texture sheepLoop2;
    TextureRegion[] animationFrames;

    public Sprite spr_player;

    private PlayScreen screen;

    public Player(PlayScreen screen) {

        this.screen = screen;

        sheepLoop2 = new Texture("sheepLoop2.png");

        TextureRegion[][] frames = TextureRegion.split(sheepLoop2, 33, 21);

        animationFrames = new TextureRegion[2];
        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                animationFrames[index++] = frames[j][i];
            }
        }

        animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1f/30f, animationFrames);

        spr_player = new Sprite(sheepLoop2);



     }

    public void update() {

        spr_player.setX(10);
        spr_player.setY(100);
        spr_player.setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,true));

    }

    public void render() {

        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    }

    public Texture getSheepLoop2() {
        return sheepLoop2;
    }
}
```

And the StackTrace is:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112)
    at com.sheep.game.Sprites.Player.update(Player.java:53)
    at com.sheep.game.Screens.PlayScreen.update(PlayScreen.java:61)
    at com.sheep.game.Screens.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:84)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.sheep.game.SheepGame.render(SheepGame.java:28)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sheep.game.Sprites.Player.update(Player.java:53)` Which line is 53? What could be null there? When you debug around that area what do you find?

Comment: Check if animationFrames are initialized properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
animationFrames = new TextureRegion[2]; // having size 2 array initialisation not TextureRegion

for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
         animationFrames[index++] = frames[j][i]; //run once according to your condition
    }
}
```

by above loop you only initialise first index, after loop `animationFrames[1]` is null

Exception here

```
animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,true) //return second TextureRegion that is still null
```

Setting null `TextureRegion` to `Sprite`.

```
spr_player.setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,true));
```

**EDIT**

If both sprite frames are horizontally arranged

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {  
       animationFrames[index++] = frames[i][j];
   }
}
```

Comment: I am only just learning and I don't really get what you mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: There are two frames both are 33 x 21 pixels